# Windows: Renaming files within cmd

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to come up with a script to do the following but I do not have and Windows Coding experience.

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a folder with multiple images in it and I want to rename it with a sequence like this

`2012.000.value`

Were value is I would like it to be able to enter a value before the script is run and the first image will be that number and then it will count up renaming that folder of images with that value.

Some images may have a file name called `Original` and I would like to retain that value but also insert the above sequence into the file name.

The images will be `.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /d %%x in (%date:~-4%.000.???) do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%y in ("%%x") do (
    set count=%%y
    for %%z in (%%x\*.jpg) do (
      ren %%~dpnxz !count!.jpg
      set /a count=count+1
    )
  )
)
endlocal
```

The above code assumes the directories will be in the format of `%CurrentYear%.000.???`. If you want multiple years, you'll need different code.

**EDIT:** This code will NOT output `000.jpg` or `001.jpg`, it will output `0.jpg` or `1.jpg`.  The code at the bottom will deal with that.

Also it will completely drop the original file name for `###.jpg` and will work with any value. If you want the original filename preserved like so `#-FileName.jpg` change the `ren` line to:

```
      ren %%~dpnxz !count!-%%~nz.jpg
```

The code will not sort the files, but will deal with them in the order that they were created in.  If you want them alphabetized, then change the `for %%z in (%%x\*.jpg) do (` line to:

```
  for /f "tokens=*" %%z in ('dir /o:n %%x\*.jpg') do (
```

---

**EDIT:** This code will output numbers of consistent length, limited by user input.

To use this code, you need to pass it how many characters you want the maximum number to be. So...

```
IMG 2
```

...can rename the files from `00.jpg` to `99.jpg` and...

```
IMG 4
```

...can rename the files from `0000.jpg` to `9999.jpg`.

`IMG.BAT`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Set how many characters the number can be. IE 00 = 2, 0000 = 4
set places=%1
set count=0
set zeros=
for /l %%x in (1,1,%places%) do set zeros=!zeros!0
for /d %%x in (%date:~-4%.000.???) do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%y in ("%%x") do (
    set count=%%y
    for %%z in (%%x\*.jpg) do (
      :: Make give !count! leading 0's if nessicary
      set count=%zeros%!count!
      :: Trim !count! down to a 4 digit number
      set count=!count:~-%places%!
      ren %%~dpnxz !count!.jpg

      :: Trim ALL 0's on the left to avoid calculation problems.
      set /a n=places-1
      for /l %%a in (0,1,!places!) do if "!count:~0,1!"=="0" set count=!count:~1!
      set /a count=count+1
    )
  )
)
endlocal
```

I prefer this method, because Windows Explorer normally sorts files alphabetically, so this would be the file order of `1.jpg` `2.jpg` `3.jpg` `10.jpg` `20.jpg`

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
2.jpg
20.jpg
3.jpg
```

But if those numbers are fixed at 3 characters width with leading 0's, the alphabetical order of them would be:

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
010.jpg
020.jpg
```

Comment: Could I make it go over 999?  Could I include an if statement to go if this value is found == original  use ` ren %%~dpnxz !count!-%%~nz.jpg` else use the original  one

Comment: @JessMcKenzie - My bad. It already could deal with number over 999 just not fixed-length numbers. I've added code that deals with that.  If you could select it as answered again and upvote it I'd appreciate it. :)